# How do you make a simple Cocoa/Objective-C text editor

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, text-editor

I want to know how to make a very, very simple text editor with Xcode. I only want it to be able to save, load, and write text files. I am just doing it out of curiosity.

Comment: Apple has the TextEdit code available on their developer site, if you want to look and see how they made that.

Comment: Also, there are open source cocoa text editors available: vico, kod and much more. You'll find them with a couple google searches.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complete project for TextEdit the text editor that comes with OS X: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TextEdit/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011741

If you want to start from scratch and do it yourself, take a look at the NSTextField class, or for saving, take a look at NSArchiver. All your pretty much have to do is create a new project, add an NSTextField to your window, and write the code to load and save the file.

Get the book Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X by Aaron Hillegass. It will show you how to get started, or just check out developer.apple.com. Lots of documentation there.

Comment: Cheers. I looked at this source code before, but wasn't sure what to make of it. That's great help, thanks.